# Assigning the id of a li element in a CollectionView with tagName ul

Tags: ember.js

I have the following js:

```
App.Menu = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
tagName: 'ul',
content: [Ember.Object.create({
    id: 'addChild',
    text: 'Als Kind Knoten'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        id: 'insertBefore',
        text: 'davor einfuegen'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        id: 'insertAfter',
        text: 'danach einfuegen'
    })],

itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({

    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("the letter: {{content.text}}")
})
});
```

and the the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.Menu id="Menu"}}

  {{/view}}
</script>
```

I don't know how I can assign content.id to the "id" attribute of the implicite generated li elements ?

Additionally I want to have an action assigned which can determine which li entry was clicked.

Best regards

Andreas

Answer (score 3):

First, Ember needs to have the generated element's id kept, unless it will no more be able to maintain it. So it does not make sense to change it.

Nevertheless, you can customize another attribute of the element, as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/EHPZV/

Moreover, you have access to the displayed element in the click handler, so what would exactly be the purpose to override containing element's id?

Comment: >>
so what would exactly be the purpose to override containing element's id?
>>

I want to store a foreign key value in the id attribute. If a list item is clicked a rest request should be performed. This request needs the foreign key for a database query which is part of the implementation of the rest service.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Using this.getPath('content.id') is the thing I was looking for.